# Why do I have to escape and second $ symbol in my Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an document inline script tag with a javascript function but I need to escape the second $ symbol? Why not escaping the both, i.e. the first and the second?

```
 $js = "<script>$(function(){\$('#slider').anythingSlider({autoPlay: true, delay: 5000, animationTime: 400, easing: \"easeInOutExpo\"});});</script>";
```

Answer (score 4):

The escaping is for the PHP.
Since you use double Quotes `"..."`, any `$..` terms within will have special meaning for the PHP parser (variable substitution).
Actually, you should also escape the first occurence of `$` in your string, or switch to a single quote string `'...'`.

Comment: it's called `string interpolation`, just for completeness ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because you use `"` quote string, and php's variable use `$`, the `$` need to escape inside a double quote string, or php parse will think that to be a variable.

Comment: Why not escaping the both, i.e. the first and the second?

Comment: because a php variable can't include special chars. Therefore, `$(something` wouldn't be a valid variable name in php.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `$` character is preceeded by a curly brace `{`, thus triggers the [complex (curly) syntax](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for variable expansion. Your first `$` does not have a curly brace, and is not followed by a valid identifier, thus does not need the backslash.